# Laravel ignore specific route. Make it open another codebase instead

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I want Laravel 5.8 to ignore a specific route and to make it open another codebase on that link instead. For example, `mysite.com` is my Laravel 5.8 app. I want `mysite.com/my-app` to open another application, which is not related to the Laravel project in `mysite.com`.

I didn't find a solution for this in the documentation and all the other things I searched for are not so applicable in my situation.

The other app is not located in the folder of the main project on `mysite.com`.

Comment: you should't define specific route. you have to put your code into `my-app` folder inside `your_laravel_app/public` folder. if you have no access to codebase, the only solution i see - iframe

Comment: This problem is related to the web server configuration rather than Laravel

Comment: what are you using to serve your site? nginx? apache? you need to set your configuration to a different location if the uri looks like that

Comment: This isn't related to laravel at all. What type of webserver are you running? You'll need to add a rule to your web server configuration to redirect that path to a different project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining a route that redirects to another URI, you may use the **Route::redirect** method. This method provides a convenient shortcut so that you do not have to define a full route or controller for performing a simple redirect. Like,

`Route::redirect('/redirect-me', 'https://www.google.com/');`